# Get Instagram data via CURL

Tags: php, curl, get, instagram

Where is error in below code? I try take the data from instagram website, for example https://www.instagram.com/nasa/media/ - I want to take it in this way don't want use API.
At the moment every thing work if I take data via `file_get_contents` but want take it via `curl` - is faster

```
<?php

function fetchData($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$result = fetchData('https://www.instagram.com/nasa/media/');
$result = json_decode($result);

?>
```

Comment: Why do you think it's faster?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your code. The $result is a stdClass object that you have access too. Just do a var_dump($result) and see what you get. There is a status ok on the call.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `file_get_contents` is so much slower then curl. In the end it depends on the response time of the server you're trying to get the information and how much requests you do.

So i would prefer `file_get_contents` in your case its much easier and needs less code. And the much important thing... its working ;)

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/nasa/media/');
```

Comment: I did it via ajax, page load faster and in background instagram photos are loading. But have a some problem, you can look on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354968/add-custom-function-to-widget-and-assign-variable-wordpress

Comment: In your case i would really cache the file for a mount of time. Don't do that request every time it's to expensive.

Comment: This doesnt work anymore (the disabled /media), This seems a good solution https://github.com/whizzzkid/instagram-proxy-api